Decrypting OpenPGP message in Node.js with private key, but receiving "No decryption key packets found" error
I'm attempting to decrypt an OpenPGP-encrypted message in a Node.js script using the openpgp library. My script runs into an error where the decryption fails with the message:
Decryption failed completely. Error details:
Error decrypting message: No decryption key packets found
The message is encrypted with the key 7851C0CAFDBF2903 (RSA 2048), and I have the corresponding private key, which is not encrypted. However, I receive the following GPG warning when I manually try to decrypt the message using the command line:
vbnet
Copy code
gpg: encrypted with rsa2048 key, ID 7851C0CAFDBF2903, created 2024-10-22
gpg: used key is not marked for encryption use.
gpg: WARNING: cipher algorithm CAST5 not found in recipient preferences
Here is the code I'm using to try to decrypt the file:
const fs = require('fs');
const openpgp = require('openpgp');

async function decryptFile(encryptedFilePath, privateKeyFilePath, passphrase, outputFilePath) {
    try {
        const encryptedData = fs.readFileSync(encryptedFilePath, 'utf8');
        const privateKeyArmored = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyFilePath, 'utf8');

        // Parse the private key
        const privateKey = await openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey: privateKeyArmored });
        console.log('Private key fingerprint:', privateKey.getFingerprint());

        // Decrypt the private key if necessary
        let decryptedPrivateKey = privateKey;
        if (privateKey.isEncrypted) {
            decryptedPrivateKey = await openpgp.decryptKey({
                privateKey,
                passphrase
            });
        }

        const message = await openpgp.readMessage({ armoredMessage: encryptedData });
        const { data: decryptedData } = await openpgp.decrypt({
            message,
            decryptionKeys: decryptedPrivateKey,
            format: 'utf8'
        });

        // Ensure output directory exists
        const outputDir = outputFilePath.substring(0, outputFilePath.lastIndexOf('/'));
        if (!fs.existsSync(outputDir)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(outputDir, { recursive: true });
        }

        fs.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, decryptedData, 'utf8');
        console.log('Decryption successful! File saved to:', outputFilePath);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Decryption failed:', error.message);
        throw error;
    }
}

async function main() {
    const encryptedFilePath = './Testd/Trade_21112024.asc';
    const privateKeyFilePath = './key/private.key';
    const passphrase = '';
    const outputFilePath = './output/Trade_21112024.csv';

    try {
        await decryptFile(encryptedFilePath, privateKeyFilePath, passphrase, outputFilePath);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Program failed:', error.message);
    }
}

main();

Issues I'm encountering:
Decryption Key Error: The error message No decryption key packets found occurs during the decryption process, even though the private key exists and is accessible.
GPG Warning: The command-line GPG tool provides a warning about the key "not being marked for encryption use" and a missing cipher algorithm CAST5, which is not found in the recipient's preferences.
What I've tried:
I've confirmed that the private key is correct and present in the private.key file.
I ensured that the private key is not encrypted (i.e., it does not require a passphrase).
I tried using both the primary private key and the subkeys for decryption in my script.
I have successfully decrypted the message manually with GPG, but I can't replicate that behavior in the Node.js script.
Questions:
Why is the decryption failing with the error No decryption key packets found in Node.js, even though I can decrypt the message manually with GPG?
How can I resolve the warning regarding the key "not marked for encryption use" and the missing CAST5 cipher algorithm?
Is there something in my Node.js decryption code that I might be overlooking, especially regarding handling subkeys or specific decryption algorithms?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

I was wrong before; cancel.

I can decrypt encrypted PGP messages with the posted NodeJS code (whereby I created the key pair and the encrypted message with CyberChef). So the problem may be in your data. How did you generate the key pair and the encrypted message? Can you post sample data?
